# PHP Upload TImeout

Tags: php

I want to upload to a php script, and I am reading conflicting info.  Some say that the 'time_out' starts as soon as the script is accessed and data is start to be placed, some say that it starts when the script receives all the data.

Anybody able to confirm which one it is?

I will be uploading files via AJAX to a script, the script only has to move the file and create a MySQL row.  So if the time out starts after all the data is received then I don't think there will be time out issues.  But if it starts once accessed, then upload times could create issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts when the script starts to run.  You can use set_time_limit() inside your function to allow it to run longer if you need to...  but it requires safe mode to be turned off.

Comment: Thanks jdu.  So as soon as the file begins its upload, the time out starts counting.   Some of the files will be quite large.  Might have to look into chucking.

Answer (score 1):

It is set at the initial start.  If you need more time use the set_time_limit()